# Put session for a Struts 2 action result of type stream

Tags: java, stream, struts2, actionresult

I have a Struts 2 action where a response of type `stream` is generated by velocity. But this is HTML and JavaScript but not all the stuff I need like session, cookie etc. How can I pass, in my action, session and cookie to the response?

**My action:**

```
@Action(value = "example", 
    results = { 
        @Result(name = "success", type = "stream", params = { "contentType", "text/html" }) 
    })
public String example() throws Exception {
    serviceId = (Long) getObjectSession("serviceId");
    selIdfile = Long.parseLong(idpreview);

    MpsServiceTemplate mpsServiceTemplate = mpsServiceTemplateDAO
            .getMpsServiceTemplateById(selIdfile);

    MpsService service = (MpsService) maasCustomDAO.loadbyId(MpsService.class, serviceId);
    
    String html = htmlBuilder.getHtml(service.getParent().getName(), service.getName(), new String(mpsServiceTemplate.getTemplateCode()), null);
    
    inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream(html);
    
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... or why you'd need those artifacts in your template. In general you want to pass only simple DTOs to your template.

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 captures servlet objects like `request`, `response`, `session` before the action is executed. You can populate your action with these objects if you use `servletConfig` interceptor in the stack. You can also access them via `ServletActionContext`. You may add `cookieProvider` interceptor to the action

> Allows actions to send cookies to client, action must implement
>   `CookieProvider`. You must reference this interceptor in your default
>   stack or in action's stack, see example below.
>
> ```xml
> <action ... >
>   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
>   <interceptor-ref name="cookieProvider"/>
>   ...
> </action>
> ```

This would allow you to pass, in your action, session and cookie to the response.

Comment: Can you make me a code example via ServletActionContext? I think I have to call getResponse and then set or add something but I don't figure out what. Thank you.

Comment: @ilasorsa Try this code `ServletActionContext.getResponse()`.